# Flutter SDK is not found specified locationFlutter SDK is not found specified location

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2ajz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjr9E.png)

I don't know what to do I have been trying for 3days

I think I have done everything right

I have seen many solutions here but nothing worked

Comment: Where have you installed flutter SDK? It says that it is not in `c:\src\flutter\flutter\bin`

Comment: I installed it inside src

Comment: Where is the `bin` folder? Android studio says that it's not inside `c:\src\flutter\flutter`

Comment: share your folder content images

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, thank you for your question! If you run the command `flutter doctor -v` in a command prompt window, then it should print out the location of the Flutter SDK. You can then use this path to configure the Flutter SDK in Android Studio.

[image: flutter doctor -v]

Answer (score 0):

First go to Envirement Variable in windows and make ANDROID_HOME variable like below:

[image]

And then add these paths in System variable path like this:

[image]

And finally you can run this command :

```
flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>
```